# How to make JavaScript dynamic?

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I want to move `document.getElementById("b")` checked in a loop.Is it possible? How can I make it happen?

```
<img class="img-responsive pic" id="picture" src="images/step1.png">
 <?php
                    //get rows query
                    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `template_design` WHERE `panel` = 'front'");    

                    if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
                        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                         $im_id = $row['id'];
                         $images = "images/" .$row['image']. "";                           
                    ?>
                 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 wel-grid wow fadeInDown">
                    <div class="wel11">
                        <input type="radio" id="<?php echo 'radio_'.$im_id; ?>" name="front" onClick="changeSrc(<?php echo  $im_id; ?>)">
                       <label  for="<?php echo 'radio_'.$im_id; ?>"  style="font-size:12px; cursor: pointer;">
                       <img  id="<?php echo 'picture_'.$im_id; ?>" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $images; ?>"></label>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             <?php } } ?>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     function changeSrc(id) {
        if (document.getElementById("radio_"+id).checked) {
     document.getElementById("picture_"+id).src = "images/Ppicture3.png";
        }
}
    </script>
```

I want to repeat it in a loop ,as fradio0 i.e $front will increment, JavaScript also repeat in a loop to match each.

Comment: you have missed an "}" on script

Comment: Edited above code,just missed out here.

Comment: solved now or still u have problem?

Comment: still i'm facing problem how to make it dynamic as id gets increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. Pass radio id as attr id & save each images by respective id's, followed by respective id.png. Also remove onclick function from your html code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("input:radio[name=front]").click(function() {
    var id= $(this).attr('id');
    document.getElementById("picture").src = "panel/front/" + id + ".png";
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters with your id for example:

```
 <input type="radio" id="<?php echo 'radio_'.$im_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $fname; ?>" onClick="changeSrc(<?php echo  $im_id; ?>)">
```

and use it on script like

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function changeSrc(id) {
        if (document.getElementById("radio_"+id).checked) {

        }
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,but 'm getting 
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input'   error

Comment: can you update the modified code with your question, so that i can identify where you have made the mistake.

Comment: where is id "picture" in your code { document.getElementById("picture").src = "images/Ppicture3.png}";

Comment: add image id like id="<?php echo 'picture_'.$im_id; ?>", and get in javascript like document.getElementById("picture_"+id) hope this is the problem in your code